# What's the best way to program c++ on a Mac?

Tags: c++, macos

What is the best software ( open source ) for programming on c++ a Mac ?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xcode, same as C and ObjC.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need anything special to program C++ on the Mac.  The only real requirement is to install the [developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html) from Apple.  This provides the compiler tool-chain and development headers needed to write and compile standards compliant C++ on OS X which is really all you need.

Once you have done that it's a case of either using Xcode to manage your projects and compile your source, or outsourcing to an external build system and possibly an external editor.

A lot of people are happy just to use the default tools.  Personally speaking I favour [textmate](http://macromates.com/) as an editor and I use [Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) as a build system so that I can compile my code on many platforms and am not tied into to OS X per-se.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse works reasonably well on Mac. The requirement that your IDE be open-source is a little odd. More important that it works well, right?

Answer (score 0):

Textmate is the best option that I've tried so far. I, personally, found Xcode rather annoying to use, and Textmate was perfect for my use. The only potential issue is that you have to pay for it (after a 30 day trial). 
You can download it at: http://macromates.com/.